# Can you catch a 'reconnected' event with Mongo Casbah?

Tags: mongodb, scala, casbah

When you have autoConnectRetry=true, is it possible to catch when the connection resumes?

I have a backup system, where some non-essential operations are stored in a file if mongo connection fails. I'm processing the operations from this file on application startup but I would also like to process them when the connection resumes.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no way to subscribe a listener to auto connects.